# Assigning an array to a gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

While trying to assign an array to the datasource of a gridview, I'm unable to get the information for each row. It only displays the last row and repeat it.

The information within the array is coming from a text file

```
Sub BindGridview()

   If Request.QueryString("show") <> "" Then
        Dim readEmailList As StreamReader = New StreamReader("d:\netdrvs\prs\emaillist\" & Request.QueryString("show"), FileMode.Open)

       While Not readEmailList.EndOfStream

            Dim readData(3) As String
            readData = Split(readEmailList.ReadLine(), vbTab)
            Dim readData2(3) As String
            readData2 = Split(readData(0), "_")

    Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()


    dt.Columns.Add("ccode", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("email", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("invnum", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dt.Columns.Add("regards", Type.GetType("System.String"))

    dim i as integer = 0

    For i = LBound(readData) to UBound(readData)
       dt.Rows.Add()
       'dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("ccode") = arrMultiD(i, 0)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("ccode") = readData2(1)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("email") = readData(1)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("invnum") = readData2(0)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("regards") = readData(2)
    Next

            gvarray.DataSource = dt
            gvarray.DataBind()

        End While


        readEmailList.Close()

        ProcessChk.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
   If Request.QueryString("show") <> "" Then
        Dim readEmailList As StreamReader = New StreamReader("d:\netdrvs\prs\emaillist\" & Request.QueryString("show"), FileMode.Open)

   Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable()

   dt.Columns.Add("ccode", Type.GetType("System.String"))
   dt.Columns.Add("email", Type.GetType("System.String"))
   dt.Columns.Add("invnum", Type.GetType("System.String"))
   dt.Columns.Add("regards", Type.GetType("System.String"))


   While Not readEmailList.EndOfStream

       Dim readData(3) As String
       readData = Split(readEmailList.ReadLine(), vbTab)
       Dim readData2(3) As String
       readData2 = Split(readData(0), "_")

       dt.Rows.Add()
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("ccode") = readData2(1)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("email") = readData(1)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("invnum") = readData2(0)
       dt.Rows(dt.Rows.Count - 1)("regards") = readData(2)

   End While


   gvarray.DataSource = dt
   gvarray.DataBind()

   readEmailList.Close()

   ProcessFile.Visible = true

  End If
```

Comment: You took my example and used it to make a self answered solution, that is bad taste - poor choice

Comment: I tried using your way and it didn't work the gridview didn't show the data at all. I did say thank you below the comment ... I'm sorry your angry with me and I'm still thankful for your help. Without your answer, it probably would have taken me a while to get it. However I will add bullying isn't nice ! I hope this question will help someone else one day.

Comment: There is no bulling, I am telling you when you take code and advise just to make your own solution - that is in poor taste. I am not angry, just disappointed in your actions.

Comment: Do you want me to hit a tick mark beside your answer even though it did not work for me? It didn't completely work and I posted what worked. And would you like me to remove the solution that worked for me as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are making the DataTable in each `While` iteration, which is wrong, put it above the While so only one is made. Then extract the data.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("ccode", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("email", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("invnum", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add("regards", Type.GetType("System.String"))
While Not readEmailList.EndOfStream
   Dim itemsArray As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object)
   Dim readData(3) As String
   readData = Split(readEmailList.ReadLine(), vbTab)
   Dim readData2(3) As String
   readData2 = Split(readData(0), "_")
   itemsArray.Add(readData2(1))
   itemsArray.Add(readData(1))
   itemsArray.Add(readData2(0))
   itemsArray.Add(readData2(1))
   Dim row = dt.NewRow()
   row.ItemArray() = itemsArray.ToArray()
End While
gvarray.DataSource = dt
gvarray.DataBind()
```

Comment: Its giving me an error on itemsArray. Compiler Error Message: BC32045: 'iTextSharp.text.List' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments.

Comment: As you can see it is trying to make a `iTextSharp.Text.List` where I am using a Generics>list

Comment: Ahh okay, I see it ... I edited my coding and when I switched it to yours the gridview disappears

Comment: That makes no sense, you will have to check the rest of your work to find that - nothing in my code would have done that.

Comment: @Sash, Make sure your data is persisted since this is an ASP app. You data also is dependent on the `queryString` so check that too.